# mysql find number of entry in a different status in descending order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | ref_id | status |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      3 |      1 |
|  2 |      4 |      0 |
|  4 |      6 |      0 |
|  6 |      8 |      1 |
|  8 |     10 |      0 |
| 10 |     12 |      1 |
| 12 |     14 |      1 |
| 14 |     16 |      0 |
| 16 |     18 |      0 |
| 18 |     20 |      0 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I want to find the number of rows that has a status 0 in descending order continuously. In this Case number would be 3

```
    +----+--------+--------+
    | id | ref_id | status |
    +----+--------+--------+
    |  1 |      3 |      1 |
    |  2 |      4 |      0 |
    |  4 |      6 |      0 |
    |  6 |      8 |      1 |
    |  8 |     10 |      1 |
    | 10 |     12 |      1 |
    | 12 |     14 |      0 |
    | 14 |     16 |      0 |
    | 16 |     18 |      0 |
    | 18 |     20 |      0 |
    +----+--------+--------+
```

In this case it is four

```
 +----+--------+--------+
    | id | ref_id | status |
    +----+--------+--------+
    |  1 |      3 |      1 |
    |  2 |      4 |      0 |
    |  4 |      6 |      0 |
    |  6 |      8 |      1 |
    |  8 |     10 |      1 |
    | 10 |     12 |      1 |
    | 12 |     14 |      0 |
    | 14 |     16 |      0 |
    | 16 |     18 |      0 |
    | 18 |     20 |      1 |
    +----+--------+--------+
```

In this case it is 0

So far I tried is processing the rows descending and finding it through php condition . Is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: Use Case When Clause in Order by clause.

Comment: How can i use case for this type of requirement

Comment: do you mean continuous till end? then you can do a simple count query `where id > (select max (id) where status = 1)`

Comment: @bansi thanks thats a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this code in codeigniter and get the result

```
$this->db->select('count(id) as number');
$this->db->from('tablename');
$this->db->where('id > (select max(id) FROM tablename where status = 1)',
NULL, FALSE);
```

In mysql

```
SELECT count(id) as number FROM tablename
WHERE id > (select max(id) FROM tablename where status = 1)
```